# How to identify which element was double clicked inside a ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I have a `listbox`. The `listbox` `DataTemplate` consists of few `Text Blocks` and some `TextBoxes`.

The issue is on mouse double click I need to find out on which element the double click was done, so as to do some further operations like make the `TextBox` editable and so on. At the same time I need to define some action for list double click also. So I can't handle mouse down separately for each component.

Hence, I need to handle the mouse down for the `ListBox` and find out on which element the double click was made.

**I tried with below code, but it returns the `ListBox`'s `Name` instead of `TextBox`'s `Name`:**

```
private void myListBox_OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{    
    var mouseWasDownOn = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
    if (mouseWasDownOn != null)
    {
        string elementName = mouseWasDownOn.Name;
    }
}
```

**I have also tried as per below questions**

[WPF Get Element(s) under mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813/wpf-get-elements-under-mouse)

[How to know what control the mouse has clicked in a canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011827/how-to-know-what-control-the-mouse-has-clicked-in-a-canvas)

[Getting the Logical UIElement under the mouse in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525774/getting-the-logical-uielement-under-the-mouse-in-wpf)

```
public void ListBox_MouseDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult target = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(myListBoxName, e.GetPosition(myListBoxName));
    while(!(target is Control) && (target != null))
    {
        target = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(target);
    }
}
```

But still could not find a solution. Hence please help me to get the element type or element name from double click.

Comment: Is it possible to use the ItemTemplate?

Comment: Oh were you trying  to say, if I handle the data template's double click event in code behind, I could get the element type or name?

Comment: Can you show your XAML code?

Comment: As @S.Akbari said, you need to show us your XAML code. But off the top of my head, you can use Style.Triggers->EventTrigger->BeginStoryboard-> Animate IsReadOnly to false in a discrete step if this is all you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName Method (String, FrameworkElement)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose and it should works as you want:

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem)
            return (childItem)child;
        childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
        if (childOfChild != null)
            return childOfChild;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then:

```
private void LstBox_OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem ListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(lstBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lstBox.SelectedIndex));
    ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(ListBoxItem);
    DataTemplate myDataTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
    StackPanel temp = (StackPanel)myDataTemplate.FindName("myStackPanel", contentPresenter);
    //*so as to do some further operations like make the textbox editable and so on* as you want
   (temp.FindName("field1TextBox") as TextBox).IsReadOnly = false;
}
```

Based on your question that you said: *The `listbox`'s `DataTemplate` consists of few `TextBlock` and some `TextBoxes`*. (I assumed they are inside a `StackPanel`)